# Administration menu

Tags: administer

I would like to ask where I can find the "Administer" so that I can enable some features in our system.  We are now using Version 4.4.2. I searched everywhere on our home/front page and couldn't find it.  We don't see any administration menu as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's to the right of the Reports menu and to the left of Support but I'm guessing the user you are using to access civicrm does not have the administer role so it doesn't show up.

There are couple of ways for permissions to be set up.  Mostly it done at the CMS level, which, will be different depending on if you are using Drupal, Joomla! or WordPress.

The online docs go over this for the different CMS's.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

(This doc is for a later version than you are running but I'm pretty sure it's mostly the same.)